# Laravel explode() array multiplefile

Tags: php, laravel

hello i have been create an multiple upload file in my `add-modal.php` something like this :

[image: multiple upload]

and the attachment is successfully `implode()` into array, here is my `controller.php`, which used to insert into my DB :

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $datatest=array();
    $request->validate([
        'attachment_name' => 'nullable',
        'attachment_name.*' => 'file|mimes:pdf|max:5048',
    ]);

    if($files = $request->file('attachment_name'))
        {
            foreach($request->file('attachment_name') as $image )
            {
                $name = date('dmY') . "-" .$image->getClientOriginalName();
                $image->move(public_path().'/storage/file/', $name);
                $datatest[] = $name;
                
            }
        }

        $insert['attachment_name'] = implode("|",$datatest);
        MediaOrder::create($insert);


    flash_success_store('Media Order successfully added.');

    if ($request->ajax()){
        return redirect_ajax_notification('media-order.index');
    }else{
        return redirect_ajax('media-order.index');
    }

}
```

and then here is the `attachment_name` or file in the datatable :

[image: result]

so i would like to `explode()` the `attachment_name`, then create a download file for each `attachment_name` array, here is my `view-modal-blade.php` which contain the download button :

[image]

as for now each `attachment_name` or the file `.pdf` is still in one value, here is my `view-modal-blade.php` value which used to placeholder the `attachment_name` value :

```
<div class="row mg-t-20">
    <label class="col-sm-4 form-control-label">ATTACHMENT:</label>

    <div class="col-sm-8 mg-t-10 mg-sm-t-0 input-group control-group increment">
        <input name="attachment_name[]" id="attachment_name_view" class="form-control" readonly></input>
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

so my question is :

Is there a way to `foreach` and `explode()` the `attachment_name` based on the data `id` an then put the`explode()` value like the first image?, so user can download each `attachment_name` file individualy? or maybe someone have an better alternate solution, thank you!.

Progress :

i have tried using `foreach(explode('|', $data->attachment_name))` but the `attachment_name` ended up becomde `undefined` for the `attachment_name`. i will provide anything that might able to help, and apologize for my english.

Comment: Show us how you save the data in the DB

Comment: i updated my controller on how the data is saved into my DB

Comment: foreach(explode('|', $data->attachment_name) as $value){
        dd($value); 
    }
in $value you will get file name

Comment: @BhargavRangani i've tried to dd in my index but the `attachment_name` is making an does not exist on this collection error , here is my code 
`$datet = MediaOrder::get();
 foreach(explode('|', $datet->attachment_name) as $data ){
 dd($data);}`

Comment: Update, never mind my previous answer, here is my code `$datet = MediaOrder::select("*")->where("id","LIKE","53")->get()->first();
foreach(explode('|', $datet->attachment_name) as $data ){dd($data);}`
and here is the dd result : `"01122021-test1.pdf"`, so my question is is there a way to use the `id` in foreach, like for example using other `id`?